# Can I log to test.log with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here's a simple spec just to test this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe A_controller do
    before do
         @cat_noise = "Meow"
    end
    it "should do nothing because it's empty and I created it just to test logger!" do
       logger.info "---------- Here comes a cat noise -----------"
       logger.info @cat_noise
       logger.info "-----------There goes a cat noise -----------"
    end
end
```

And here's my log level configuration for the test environment:

```
  config.log_level = :info
```

However, I'm getting nothing to do with cat noises in my `test.log` file. Should I be? Would it appear in `test.log`? It would be good to double check factories and the like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where that `logger` variable comes from. There is no `logger` available inside an RSpec block. The code should crash with

```
NameError:
  undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007ffa3208b478>
```

In order to write to the Rails log, you should use

```
Rails.logger
```

Thus

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe A_controller do
    before do
        @cat_noise = "Meow"
    end

    it "should do nothing because it's empty and I created it just to test logger!" do
       Rails.logger.info "---------- Here comes a cat noise -----------"
       Rails.logger.info @cat_noise
       Rails.logger.info "-----------There goes a cat noise -----------"
    end
end
```